# "Neuter alteri plenam copiam pecuniae tum dabit"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, wheelocks-latin

This is the fourth exercitationes from chapter nine of Wheelock's 7th edition latin textbook. Im translating some sentences as practice for a final exam.

I translated the sentence as "Neither of the other will give full blame to wealth at that time." Can someone check this? I may be missing something here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't correct. You've made three mistakes here. First, *copiam* does not mean "blame." Once you figure out it's real meaning, you'll also then ideally figure out what's wrong with *pecuniae*, which is not the indirect object. And then once you got that part, you'll realize what you did wrong with *alteri*, which is not a genitive. That would be *alterius*. So what could *alteri* be then?

Comment: So I guess i confused copia with culpa, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hydrolox3552 Easy mistake to make! Let me know if still need further help.